# PHP select query not getting updated records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a php form using POST and use dynamic HTML tables. I truncate the DB table every time before inserting the data in to the table which seems fine.

**Select query when the page loads (to update UI part)**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLENAME';
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);
$rows = array();
if(!$result)
{
    //log error
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        print_r( $row);
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
```

**Insert part**

```
if(isset($_POST['u']))
{
    foreach($_POST['u'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $ky = $_POST['x'][$key];

        $query = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID,KY) VALUES ($value, '$ky')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);
    }
}
```

However, upon posting, when using select query, it seems to not get the latest records inserted, I made sure to check the records are inserted properly in PhpMyadmin.

When I reload the page, it works fine. Only thing is it's not getting the updated records when it's POSTed, but works the subsequent times.

I thought it could be due to connection object and tried to use different connections objects with no luck.

INFO: Not sure if it has any impact, the database is a wordpress and I created new table in this database for this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what does result give you? does the query run outside of php?

Comment: And where is the form that's generating the POST?

Comment: @NickMaroulis the result of the select query is not updated, say if I currently have 2 rows of data and I add 1 row by posting, the select query will return the old data of 2 rows. But when I reload the same page again, it will fetch 3 rows.

Comment: If the select statement appears in your code before the insert statement, that's your problem.  You need to select after the insert if you want to get the newly inserted row.

Comment: @devlincarnate  Of course, the select appears before the insert, but when the form is already posted and the page is loaded, I am not sure if it matters if the select has to be before or after insert.

Comment: Is the insert in a separate php page that you're posting to?

Comment: @Questions A `SELECT` query is sent to the database, and the database, at that exact point in time, assembles a record set for the query and passes that back to PHP. That's it then. It's done. Now if you `INSERT` new records, you will have to requery to see them. The `SELECT` you already did will not be updated. In other words a `SELECT` statement is not living connection to the database. It's a query that grabs records once and dies. Lastly, I like your username.

Comment: @JNevill I know how SELECT works. INSERT is part of the form POST. When the POST is complete and it comes back to the same page, I have a SELECT query there which I expect to get the latest inserted records from the last POST. I hope I am clear in explaining it.

Comment: @Questions - are you posting to the same page or a different page?  If it's the same page, then the select is happening before the insert.

Comment: My apologies. It sounded, and looked from the code, that you were performing a SELECT, then INSERT, then wondering why your SELECT didn't reflect the INSERTed records.

Comment: If you are posting to a separate page, please show how you return the user back to the original page.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Yes, @devlincarnate I agree that there is something we aren't seeing that is most likely the cause. If I've got this straight, we are POSTing a form to a page, which does the INSERT. All is well at this point. Then... somehow the page redirects to another page (or perhaps itself) where it then does a SELECT. Which is not showing the new records. Which leads me to believe that it's not redirecting or reloading the page after INSERT. Need more code here to troubleshoot.

Comment: From these comments, it still looks to me that the SELECT is happening too early. @Questions, just for kicks, even if it makes the UI look wrong, put the INSERT code above the SELECT code to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to do a `SELECT` query after your `INSERT` query in order to get the full data set.

You might consider posting to a separate page, and then redirect the user back to the original page after the `INSERT`.  This will cause the `SELECT` to run again, since the page reloads.

Comment: Yes. Even if the UPDATE php stuff is after the HTML form, it won't run until the page loads the second time, AFTER the SELECT is run again.